# SOAP XSL Integration error during upsert: "cannot specify Id"

Tags: integration, error, soap, upsert

Below is an example of the SOAP request that is being sent to Salesforce from our app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <SessionHeader xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <sessionId>...</sessionId>
        </SessionHeader>
        <CallOptions xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <client>...</client>
            <defaultNamespace>...</defaultNamespace>
        </CallOptions>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <upsert xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <externalIDFieldName>CPQ_External_Id__c</externalIDFieldName>
            <sObjects xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
                ...
                <CPQ_External_Id__c>123456</CPQ_External_Id__c>
                <Transaction_ID__c>123456</Transaction_ID__c>
                <Id>some_id</Id>
                <Start_Upserting_Lines__c>true</Start_Upserting_Lines__c>
            </sObjects>
        </upsert>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But we receive the following error, which btw I'm not sure in which part of the communication is happening:

> Could not perform Action: Save
> During commerce integration Process ID: ..., Name: Lightning Quote Upsert
> Exception occurred for Integration Process ID: ..., Name: Lightning Quote Upsert
> cannot specify Id in an insert call

However, in the SOAP example I see there is a tag for upserting lines that is set to true, and also the whole content of the body it's surrounded by the upsert tag as well.

Have you ever seen an error like this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What did you set the `externalIDFieldName` to?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox , I've added that part of the code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using an External ID field, you are not allowed to specify `<Id>` as well. You need to remove the `<Id>` from the `upsert()` call to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've removed the line "<externalIDFieldName>CPQ_External_Id__c</externalIDFieldName>", but now I get another error: "An error occurred while communicating with the partner site. Error message from the partner site: Unexpected element {urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com} type during simple type deserialization"

Comment: @Gonzalo No, you need to remove the `<Id>`. My apologies if the wording was ambiguous.

Comment: Fox, it works like a charm. I'm going to mark this answer but also continue my testing. The weird thing is, I started to do my testing with the SOAP Generator template that was already in our app, so when I put back the BKP file, the error continued. I guess there was a difference between the saved and deployed versions? Who knows. Have you seen something like that?

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox, now I'm getting another error if I continue working on the application. Here is the message: "found duplicate value: cafsl__CPQ_External_Id__c duplicate value in registry with ID: aJD250000008OpJ"... Maybe it's related with my previous comment.

Comment: @Gonzalo If you have parallel requests executing, that can cause the error you're getting. The good news: this means your SOAP payload is likely working correctly. Now, you just need to avoid sending duplicate ID values in close proximity with each other. See [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318436&type=1).

Comment: I went to our PROD env. and printed a preview of the SOAP Payload and it has both the Id and the External ID field, ¿how is that possible? Because PROD it's currently working fine... The only difference I see is that the Endpoint URL doesn't have the same structure: in UAT is https://some_name.uat.my.salesforce.com/ and in PROD is https://some_name.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/31.0/some_number... Could that had something to do with that behaviour?

Comment: I also don't understand why the error mentions I cannot provide ID when performing an INSERT but I see in the SOAP payload that we are sending an UPSERT

Comment: @Gonzalo I believe the error is "generic." There's a few errors in Salesforce that are like that. Don't get too hung up on it. Like I said before, you might be running into concurrent upsert problems.